# SQL delete row from parent only if child does not exist

Tags: sql

I’m new here but I hope one of you can help me.

**I need to create a table where it is not possible to delete a parent entry as long as the child exists.**

I hope this makes my problem understandable.

Comment: Google `Foreign key`

Comment: this is an extremely basic relational database concept.  Look into table relationships/foreign keys.

Comment: this is slightly general

Answer (score 0):

Create a primary key on Parent table and make that key as foreign key in child table and during insert to child table must insert the Parent tables primary key to childs table foreign key